# OpenLayers Style Question ... not working in IE

Tags: open-source-gis, openlayers-2, javascript

I'm trying to use OpenLayers to produce a map I'm using the following to style a layer in the map.

It seems to work fine in Firefox but I get javascript error in IE 'symbolizer' is null or not an object ....?
Any Ideas?

```
var previewVectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("previewVector", { isBaseLayer: true,

          styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
              strokeColor: "white",
              strokeWidth: 1
            }, {
              rules: [
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                  filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "leUsage",
                    value: "Bulk Commodity"
                  }),
                  symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: "olive"
                  }
                }),
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                  filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "leUsage",
                    value: "Service Industry"
                  }),
                  symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: "pink"
                  }
                }),
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                  filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "leUsage",
                    value: "Car Precincts"
                  }),
                  symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: "blue"
                  }
                }),
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                  filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "leUsage",
                    value: "Container Trade"
                  }),
                  symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: "green"
                  }
                }),
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                  filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "leUsage",
                    value: "Warehousing and Container Park"
                  }),
                  symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: "navyblue"
                  }
                }),
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                  filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "leUsage",
                    value: "Other"
                  }),
                  symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: "brown"
                  }
                }),
            ]
            })
          })
        });
```

Comment: http://www.jslint.com -- quickly picks out typos in even the most complex javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a... DEVIANT COMMA!!!

Just delete that comma after:

```
                symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: "brown"
                  }
                }),
```

*evil comma breaking IE* ^

Try this: `alert([1,2,3,].length);`

Comment: evil comma :) cheers all fixed, I run firebug for firefox would have thought it would pick that up .... ahh well

Comment: **Jamo**: I allways use firebug for debugging, and IE to tell me if any errors are present in my code. For me its a great combo :)

Comment: Neither will tell you there is a comma out of place. Its just one of those many quirks you just have to know when it comes to cross browser JS. All you get is 'null or not an object'.